# привет всем ) учусь верстать у меня такая проблема хочу прижать footer к низу окна браузера) но почему то не получается ПРОБОВАЛ использовать flex

Tags: html, css

```css
*::before,
*::after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
img{
    vertical-align: top;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500 ;
    font-family: Montserrat, serif;
}
.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}
._container{
    max-width: 1046px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 15px ;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/*
.................шапка .............................................................
*/
.header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 50;
/*    background: black;*/
}

.header_container{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 104px;
    align-items: center;

}
.header_logo{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:inherit;

}
.header_menu{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 450px;
}
.menu{
padding: 5px;
}
.menu_list{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;

}

.menu_item{

}
.menu_item:not(:last-child){
    margin: 0px 21px 0px 0px ;
}
.menu_link{
    font-weight: 600;

}
.header_cor{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 39px ;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .header_menu{
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 100px ;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .header_menu{
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px ;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 594px) {
    .header_menu{
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px ;
    }
}
/*.................main.............................................................*/

.page{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin-top: 116px;
}
/*.................подвал .............................................................*/
.footer{
    margin-top: 116px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
         <div class="wrapper">
                <header class="header">
               <div class="header_container _container">
                   <a href="" class="header_logo">
                       Relvise
                   </a>
                   <nav class="header_menu menu">
                       <ul class="menu_list">
                           <li class="menu_item">
                               <a href="" class="menu_link">Home</a>
                           </li>
                           <li class="menu_item">
                               <a href="" class="menu_link">Product</a>
                           </li>
                           <li class="menu_item">
                               <a href="" class="menu_link">Pricing</a>
                           </li>
                           <li class="menu_item">
                               <a href="" class="menu_link">Contact</a>
                           </li>

                           <div class="header_cor">

                               <img src="imd/Vector11.png" height="16" width="16"/>
                           <img src="imd/Vector 22.png" height="12" width="16"/>
                               </div>
                       </ul>
                   </nav>
         </div>
         </header>
              <main class="page">
                 <div class="page_main-block main-block">
                         <div class="main_block_container _container">
                             <div class="main_block_body">
                             <h1 class="main-block_title">Finance and Consultancy Solution
                             </h1>
                             <div class="main-block_text">
                                 We know how large objects will act,
                                 but things on a small scale.
                                    </div>
                             <div class="main-block_buttons">
                                 <a href="" class="main-block_button">Get Quote Now</a>
                                 <a href="" class="main-block_button main-block_button_border">Learn More</a>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                 </div>
               </main>
                 <footer class="footer ">
                     я подвал
                 </footer>

         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `.wrapper` установите `min-height: 100vh`, а чтобы между `.page` и `footer` было пространство (чтобы `footer` был прижат) - укажите `.page` `margin-bottom: auto`.

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Montserrat, serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

._container {
  max-width: 1046px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/*
.................шапка .............................................................
*/

.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  /*    background: black;*/
}

.header_container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 104px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header_logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: inherit;
}

.header_menu {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 450px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu_list {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.menu_item {}

.menu_item:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0px 21px 0px 0px;
}

.menu_link {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.header_cor {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 39px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .header_menu {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .header_menu {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 594px) {
  .header_menu {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  }
}


/*.................main.............................................................*/

.page {
  margin-top: 116px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}


/*.................подвал .............................................................*/

.footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header_container _container">
      <a href="" class="header_logo">Relvise</a>
      <nav class="header_menu menu">
        <ul class="menu_list">
          <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="" class="menu_link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="" class="menu_link">Product</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="" class="menu_link">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="" class="menu_link">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <div class="header_cor">
            <img src="imd/Vector11.png" height="16" width="16" />
            <img src="imd/Vector 22.png" height="12" width="16" />
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="page">
    <div class="page_main-block main-block">
      <div class="main_block_container _container">
        <div class="main_block_body">
          <h1 class="main-block_title">Finance and Consultancy Solution</h1>
          <div class="main-block_text">We know how large objects will act, but things on a small scale.</div>
          <div class="main-block_buttons">
            <a href="" class="main-block_button">Get Quote Now</a>
            <a href="" class="main-block_button main-block_button_border">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer ">
    я подвал
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое ) помогло

Comment: @gleb, Если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный (галочка под рейтингом ответа)